# Silverlight PivotViewer dynamic collections best practices

Tags: silverlight, pivot, pivotviewer

I'm new to Silverlight PivotViewer.  My goal is to create an image for each sale in my database.  The image is to contain data for the sales rep, sale date, invoice amount, customer, etc.  I'm using the Html template approach [see here](http://programmerpayback.com/2010/08/02/silverlight-pivotviewer-app-online-jigsaw-puzzles/) and am having success generating images with this approach.

My sales volume over the past couple of years is several hundred thousand sales.  I need to be able to query subsets of sales based on different criteria.  My process is as sales are generated, I'm creating the sale image via Html template and saving that image to file system.  My vision is to create a UI where user can enter filtering criteria (sales date range, sales rep, etc)and produce a collection of saved images and display them in Silverlight Pivotviewer.  What's the best way to do this?

My initial thought is to generate the cxml file on the fly after the user enters filtering criteria.  Is this the best approach?  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully done a Silverlight PivotViewer using PivotServerTools from Microsoft. I dynamically create the Images and retrieve the data from a database. Here is a link to help you out. [PivotServerTools](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/pivot-viewer/just-in-time-sample-code)

Answer (score 1):

You might have already resolved this, but you are heading down the correct path.  The image generation is the most difficult and costly part of the process.  By generating the images as the data is created you are saving yourself a lot of load time.  CXML generation is quick and fairly easy.  So I would follow the path that you are on: dynamic CXML generation off of filters and oncreated generation of the images.

Tony